# Python list index out of range issue

Tags: python

Currently appending a integer parsed from a file name into an array as I iterate through all the files in the directory. I keep getting a list index out of range error.
Parse Format:     `LOG-rank-2-die-30-delay-7000000-.txt`

```
    for filenamelogs in sorted(os.listdir('test_log_data/%s' %(directory_name))):
        delay_times.append(filenamelogs.split('-')[6])
        print delay_times
```

The array is appending the data I want on each pass and even finishes all the data appends required, yet I get this index issue. What am I not seeing?

```
['7000000']
['7000000', '5000000']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testv2.py", line 478, in <module>
    format_overall_stats(dir_name, workbook_file_name, 3)
  File "testv2.py", line 202, in format_overall_stats
    delay_times.append(filenamelogs.split('-')[6])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Some of your ```filenamelogs``` don't have seven items when split?  Put a try/except block around it and print the offending *logs* in the ```except``` suite to see what's up.

Comment: Hmm, they all do (in my eyes). Good point though, I'll try it.

Comment: It looks like your `filenamelogs` do not have *atleast* 7 columns, which you assume they do.. Hence the error. If you do `print filenamelogs.split('-')` - you would know how many columns

Comment: Totally forgot I had this file in there that followed a different format. Caught in the exception handler. Thanks!

Comment: You should answer your own question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to wwii, I forgot there was a file in there not following the parsing syntax I coded.